# Oracle: Query identical table in multiple schema in single line

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, union

In Oracle, is there a way to query the same, structurally identical table out of multiple schema within the same database in single line?  Obviously assuming the user has permissions to access all schema, I could build a query like:

```
select * from schema1.SomeTable
union all
select * from schema2.SomeTable
```

But is it possible, given the right permissions to say something like:

```
select * from allSchema.SomeTable
```

...and bring back all rows for all the schema?  And related to this, is it possible to pick which schema, such as:

```
select * from allSchema.SomeTable where schemaName in ('schema1','schema2')
```

Comment: No.  What you want to do is not possible with a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option, as far as I can tell, is to create a VIEW (as UNION of all tables across all those users), and then SELECT FROM VIEW.

For example:

```
create or replace view my_view as
  select 'schema_1' source_schema, id, name from schema_1.table union
  select 'schema_2' source_schema, id, name from schema_2.table union
  ...

-- select all
select * from my_view;

-- select all that belongs to one of schemas
select * from my_view where source_schema = 'schema_1';
```

Comment: Use UNION ALL instead of UNION, so the DB doesn't have to sort the data to eliminate duplicate records, unless you want the distinct rows that is.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, I agree. Thank you.